# .NET Runtime Optimization Service

Tags: .net, windows, optimization, service

I noticed that the service **.NET Runtime Optimization Service v2.0.50727_X86** is disabled. This is the associated executable:

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorsvw.exe

I think I might have disabled this service...not sure. Do I need it? Should it be running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is my understanding that this is something [NGen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20620348/1497596) uses only when new framework assemblies are installed.